# Upper and Lower Bounds: Terminology

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have a function that has no upper bound (i.e. is not bounded from above), is it acceptable to say that its upper bound is at infinity? If not, is there any way to describe that property, other than "not bounded from above"?

Comment: For the record, I suggested an edit adding the four tags "functions", "elementary-set-theory", "terminology", and "upper-lower-bounds", but [it was rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2007293).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally one says the function is "unbounded", although this has some ambiguity, as it could take on arbitrarily large positive values or arbitrarily large negative values. A slightly more natural way to phrase your statement is "not bounded above" rather than "not bounded from above".

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, we need to identify the context in question. However, let us first recall the following definition:

Let $(X, \prec )$ be an ordered set and $A$ a subset of $X$. We call $b$ an *upper bound* for the subset $A$ if $b$ is an **element** of $X$ such that for any $a \in A$ we have $a \prec b$.

Now, there are two possible contexts in question:

- $(X, \prec ) = (\mathbb{R} , < )$; in this case there are subsets that do not have an upper bound, which are called *unbounded from above*. It should be noted that here the infinity, $\infty$, is neither an element nor a subset of $X$, it just a *symbol*, which is usually used to study behavior of functions for unboundedly large values, so saying statements like "upper bound is (at) infinity" does **not** seem appropriate, according to our definition of upper bound, for which the context could be mistaken for the one below.
- $(X, \prec ) = (\bar{\mathbb{R}}, < ')$. The set $\bar{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{ - \infty , +\infty \}$ denotes the extended real number system, and the order relation $< '$ is the usual order $<$ for any two elements $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, together with $-\infty < ' a$ and $a < ' + \infty$ for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $-\infty < ' + \infty$. In this case subsets which are unbounded from above in $(\mathbb{R} , < )$ now have the upper bound $+ \infty$ in $(\mathbb{ R}, < ' )$, so it is appropriate to say that the upper bound of such sets is $+ \infty$.